# Scanf in the third prompt get skipped, even if I add a space before the %d

Tags: c, scanf

My scanf function keeps getting skipped. Here is a sample for the code:

```
int size, size2;


  printf("Enter the number of elements in the first array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  char arr[size];
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Enter the number of elements in the second array: ");
  scanf(" %d", &size2);
  char arr2[size2];
  for (int i=0; i<size2; i++){
    scanf("%c", &arr2[i]);
  }
```

The scanf for the size2 prompt is always skipped. Why is this?

Comment: Debug your program and pay *very* close attention to the content of `arr`. I think you're going to find that hits its first iteration unexpectedly quickly due to the leftover content of the newline left after entering `size`. therefore, some character *not-a-digit* will be left in the input stream upon encounter of the `scanf` for `size2`, which will fail completely unchecked because absolutely none of this has *any* IO validation whatsoever. Worst of all, now you're heading into the VLA sizing of `arr2` using an indeterminate `size2` value, and you've officially tipped into the abyss.

Comment: Always check return value of any input function, and especially `scanf`. Read what the value means.

Comment: Use `” %c”` to skip white space.  When you type `4` for the.number of entries in the first array and then type `1357` for the data, the value in `arr1[0]` is the newline after the 4, and then 1`, `3`, `5` are read.  The second prompt finds 7 and newline in the input, and goes ahead filling `arr2[0]` with the newline typed after the 7, before waiting for more data.

Answer (score 0):

You Can insert each step logs in your loops ,
ex :

```
printf("Enter the number of elements in the first array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  
  char arr[size];
  
  for (int i=0; i<size; i+=1){
    printf("start of round %d  ",i);
    scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
    printf("end of round %d  ",i);
  }
  
  printf("Enter the number of elements in the second array: ");
  scanf(" %d", &size2);
  char arr2[size2];
  for (int i=0; i<size2; i++){
    printf("start of round %d  ",i);
    scanf("%c", &arr2[i]);
    printf("end of round %d  ",i);
  }
```

content of logs in first loop:

start of round 0  end of round 0 start of round 1 (input !! # jump to round 1!)

...

**you can use %s instead of %c**

```
printf("Enter the number of elements in the first array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  char arr[size];

  for (int i=0; i<size; i+=1){
    printf("start of round %d  ",i);
    scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
    printf("end of round %d  ",i);
  }

  printf("Enter the number of elements in the second array: ");
  scanf(" %d", &size2);
  char arr2[size2];
  for (int i=0; i<size2; i++){
    printf("start of round %d  ",i);
    scanf("%s", &arr2[i]);
    printf("end of round %d  ",i);
  }
```

This trick worked for me!

Comment: Using `%s` leads to buffer overflow.